# Xcode15 duplicate symbol

Tags: duplicates, sdk, symbols, libraries, xcode15

I upgraded xcode15 and encountered a 'duplicate symbol' error,The reason is that my SDK has duplicates。
I have 4 static libraries, namely A, B, C, and D,A Link binary with libraries B and C,B and C Link binary with libraries D,build A error duplicate symbol.

I don't know how to set it in xcode to solve this error